# Python Redis Queue (rq) - how to avoid preloading ML model for each job?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I want to queue my ml predictions using rq. Example code (pesudo-ish):

`predict.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def predict_stuff(foo):
    model = tf.load_model()
    result = model.predict(foo)
    return result
```

`app.py`:

```
from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis
from predict import predict_stuff

q = Queue(connection=Redis())
for foo in baz:
    job = q.enqueue(predict_stuff, foo)
```

`worker.py`:

```
import sys
from rq import Connection, Worker

# Preload libraries
import tensorflow as tf

with Connection():
    qs = sys.argv[1:] or ['default']

    w = Worker(qs)
    w.work()
```

I've read rq docs explaining that you can preload libraries to avoid importing them every time a job is run (so in example code I import tensorflow in the worker code). However, I also want to move model loading from `predict_stuff` to avoid loading the model every time the worker runs a job. How can I go about that?

Comment: I tried moving the model load outside `predict_stuff` and importing `predict` inside the `worker`, but then the model is loaded in `app` as well, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is something that can help but, following the example here:

https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/720

Instead of sharing a connection pool, you can share the model.

pseudo code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from rq import Worker as _Worker
from rq.local import LocalStack

_model_stack = LocalStack()

def get_model():
    """Get Model."""
    m = _model_stack.top
    try:
        assert m
    except AssertionError:
        raise('Run outside of worker context')
    return m

class Worker(_Worker):
    """Worker Class."""

    def work(self, burst=False, logging_level='WARN'):
        """Work."""
        _model_stack.push(tf.load_model())
        return super().work(burst, logging_level)

def predict_stuff_job(foo):
    model = get_model()
    result = model.predict(foo)
    return result
```

I use something similar to this for a "global" file reader I wrote. Load up the instance into the LocalStack and have the workers read off the stack.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I haven't figured out how to do it with python-rq. I moved to celery where I did it like this:

`app.py`

```
from tasks import predict_stuff

for foo in baz:
    task = predict_stuff.delay(foo)
```

`tasks.py`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_process_init

cel_app = Celery('tasks')
model = None

@worker_process_init.connect()
def on_worker_init(**_):
    global model
    model = tf.load_model()

@cel_app.task(name='predict_stuff')
def predict_stuff(foo):
    result = model.predict(foo)
    return result
```